# Monotonicity of $f(x)-g(x)$ where $g$ is asymptotically greater than $f$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

If $g(x) \succ f(x)$ (or $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$), will $g(x)-f(x)$ *always* be a strictly increasing function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can oscillate, consider $f(x) \equiv 1$ and $g(x) = e^x+ \sqrt{x}\sin e^{x^2}$. On average, the difference grows, but it oscillates while doing so.

Comment: What about functions which don't have any oscillating components?

Comment: Then you can still have stretches where $f$ grows faster than $g$. The asymptotics only give the overall behaviour when $x\to\infty$, the local behaviour can be different.